# Getting The selector "app" did not match any elements

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I've trimmed this down to the barest of data and I'm baffled as to what is going on. I'm getting the selector not found error in angular 2. Trying to figure out what the problem is, it was working an hour ago now I've added a comma or space or done something to break it and I can't figure out what I've changed! Arrrg

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

boot.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <h1>component works!</h1>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
<base href="/">
<title>Angular 2 Boilerplate</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Load libraries -->
<!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js">             </script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/app.css">
</head>
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>

<script>
System.config({
    packages: {
        app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nuts, realized I didn't paste the app.component.ts correctly, editing now

Comment: Then delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh no,

I changed the selector name.. duuuh

in the html I need to change `<my-app></my-app>` to just `<app></app>` or vice versa. After I changed the selector name in the ts component file it worked.

ug..

Answer (score 1):

In your html file, you need to change `<my-app>` to `<app>`

```
....
</head>
<body>
<app>Loading...</app> <!-- this should match your root component selector -->

<script>
....
```